# To check continuity of $f(z) = \begin{cases} {\frac{{\bar{z}}^3}{z Re z}}, & \text if {z}\neq {0} \\ 0, & \text{if z=0} \end{cases}$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I want to check continuity of $f(z) = \begin{cases} {\frac{{\bar{z}}^3}{z Re z}},  & \text{if} {z}\neq {0} \\ 0, & \text{if z=0} \end{cases}$

Here polynomial function ${\frac{{\bar{z}}^3}{z Re z}}$ is defined and continuous on everywhere except on z=0 and on Y-axis.

To check continuity at z=0 ,I considered $\lim_{z\to 0}{\frac{{\bar{z}}^3}{z Re z}}$ and I evaluated this limit along all possible paths I got answer zero .Infact I want to show that $\lim_{z\to 0}{\frac{{\bar{z}}^3}{z Re z}}=0$ that is continuous at 0. How can I proceed.

Comment: Your function isn't well-defined in a neighborhood around zero. Perhaps you meant to split the cases on $\text{Re}(z)$ instead of $z$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$

$\bar{z}=x-iy$

Let $z\in \mathbb{R}$

$\implies y=0$

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(x-iy)^3}{(x+iy)\cdot Re(z)}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(x-0)^3}{x\cdot x}=\lim_{z\to 0}x=0$$

Let $z\in i\mathbb{R}$

$\implies x=0$
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(x-iy)^3}{(x+iy)\cdot Re(z)}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(0-iy)^3}{iy\cdot 0}\  \text{ is not defined}$$

Hence, $f(z)= \frac{{\bar{z}}^3}{z Re z}$ isn't continuous at $z=0$